# How to assign a variable in logstash config?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to fetch the host name from the events that logstash processes, and if the events matches to the criteria I want the host name to be sent to another file. But meanwhile the event should be sent to elasticsearch output.

The idea what am having is to assign the host name to a variable, and send the variable value to a file, if the "if" condition is satisfied.

Will this be possible with logstash?

Regards,
Gaurav

Answer (score 3):

Yes, what you want is posible in Logstash. The Logstash site has documentation for the config format, and all the available plugins which can be found at http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/. You will probably want to use the [grok filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/filters/grok) to extract the host name, and the [file output](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/outputs/file) to write the data.


Here is an example confg, which does what you want:

```
 input {
     #some input
 } 
 filters { 
     grok {
         match => ["message", "%{HOSTNAME:host} rest of message line" ]
         add_tag => ["has_hostname"]
     }
 }
 output {
    elasticsearch {}
    if "has_hostname" in [tags] {
        file {
            message_format => "%{host}"
            path => "path/to/file"
        }
    }
 }
```

The grok pattern will need to be altered to match your data, the logstash docs include a link the default pattern set that you can use.

Comment: add_tag appears to work but searching for an item in a list (of tags) can be computationally expensive when carried out per record. It would be great to see a solution that uses a variable to carry out the same task.